# Send auto generated passwords to particular group users

Tags: magento

I created a `customer group` named `corporate users` and i uploaded bulk emails into that group. Now i need to send auto generated passwords to all users under `corporate users` user group. Id of that user group is "4".

So far i tried with http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/67065/

But this one didn't worked me. Did any one went through these kind of issues.

Any solution is really appreciated !!

Comment: What do you mean by "uploaded bulk emails into that group"?

Comment: Means i uploaded 100+ contacts as csv format by giving group id. And i exported that csv file. Now all new uploaded users are under my new contact group named "Corporate Users". Now i need to know how to send auto generated passwords to those users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this doesn't work directly, it should be a start.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',true);
include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

Mage::app();

$coll = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');
// or $coll = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
/* @var $coll Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection */
/* or Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Customer_Collection < CE1.6 */
$coll->addFieldToFilter('group_id',4);

/*
 * Use the SPL IteratorAggregate implementation of Magento collections.
 * @var $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
 * @see Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController->saveAction()
 */
foreach ($coll as $customer) {
    $customer->setForceConfirmed(true);
    $sendPassToEmail = true;
    $customer->setPassword($customer->generatePassword());
    $customer->save();
    $customer->sendNewAccountEmail('registered', '', $customer->getStoreId());
}
```

Comment: I know that this updates the password field and triggers mail->send.

Comment: Glad to hear. Mark the answer as accepted if it is in fact a solution so that others may find it.